# Problems defining the port for remote connection in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I use the following connection string to establish a remote connection in SQL Server:

```
 "Data Source=" + _databaseIP + "," + _databasePort + ";Network
Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=SI_CONFIG; uid=sa;pwd=Password1!"
```

where the _databaseIP and _databasePort are input by the user.

However, although the IP is fixed on the remote machine, the port eventually changes.
To discover the actual port where the server is listening I look for the ERRORLOG file ('c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG') and search for the line 'Server is listening on [ 'any'  49167' which tells me the port, however, this seems to change randomly after some days or weeks.

I wanted the port to be fixed, or to use another way to connect through the server, in a way which I did not demand the port anymore from the user. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please see this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345327(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your SQL Server is configured to use a [dynamic port](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx).  From the link:

> Named instances of the Database Engine and SQL Server Compact are
>   configured for dynamic ports. This means they select an available port
>   when the SQL Server service is started. When you are connecting to a
>   named instance through a firewall, configure the Database Engine to
>   listen on a specific port, so that the appropriate port can be opened
>   in the firewall.

To configure your SQL instance to use a specific port instead, open up the Sql Server Configuration Manager and navigate to Sql Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for (instance name).  Right-click **TCP/IP**, go to Properties -> IP Addresses tab, and clear all the entries for TCP Dynamic Ports.  Set the **TCP Port** value for each IP address on which you want to make connections available.  SQL will need to be restarted after you save your changes.